# Why $\vec{E} = \frac{\sigma}{2 {\epsilon}}$ does not has a variable for distance?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

Upon solving a question where I had to find the Electric Field  $\vec{E}$ due to an infinitely large uniformly charged sheet of charge density ${\sigma}$ , I found that the Electric Field at a point near the surface is given by $\frac{\sigma}{2 {\epsilon}}$.

But Electric Field is property that is dependent on the distance from the charged body. So why does this equation

$\vec{E} = \frac{\sigma}{2 {\epsilon}}$ does not have a variable for the distance factor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the field from a individual charge varies as the inverse square of the distance from the charge, if you integrate the contribution of each charge from an infinite plane of charge the resulting field is constant (independent of distance). A proof can be found here: http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/mchutchon/chargedPlanes.pdf

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the charged sheet is infinitely long. So any finite distance from the sheet is very small with respect to the sheet. In other words, from any point at some finite distance from the sheet, the sheet would appear to be infinitely extended. If the x=0 plane, i.e., the y-z plane be the charged sheet with surface charge density $\sigma$ , then at any point $P(x\neq{0},y,z)$ from the plane, the electric field **E** is due to all the charges in the infinite plane as well as the charge induced on the plane by the unit test charge placed at P. So the electric field does not change in magnitude, the direction being either into or out of the plane depending on the sign of $\sigma$ . However, the result will vary if the plane is finite. If you try to imagine this, I hope you will be able to look into this.

Comment: The test charge is considered to --> 0 in the limit so should not change the E field due to the charged sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the sheet to lie in a horizontal plane and we want to find the E field above it at a point P. Note that the horizontal component of E from charges to the left and right of P cancel (since there's as much charge to the left as there is to the right) and only the vertical components add. Now when P is close to the sheet, 1/r is large but the contributions are mainly horizontal (which cancel). As P gets further from the sheet, the vertical components predominate but because of 1/r they are smaller in magnitude. It just "works out" that because of this relation - 1/r diminishing but the contribution to E becoming more vertical - the E field is independent of r.